# How to change the pitch but keep the speed FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Since I already know how to use the asetrate code to change both pitch and sound, however, I would like to find out of how can I only just change the pitch but retain the original speed. Can anyone help me with this, please?

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "source.mp3" -codec:a pcm_s16le -af "asetrate=48000*1.042709" "output.wav"`

Here is the code above that I normally use for the 23.976 to 25fps (PAL speed-up) pitch and speed conversion.

Comment: I used google, but other search engines probably work too - my search criteria was `ffmpeg change pitch only` and I found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374590/ffmpeg-change-tone-frequency-keep-length-pitch-audio - does that help?

Comment: Thanks, @Bravo, It worked, your right I should have just searched easily on Google but thanks again for providing me with this external link, very grateful.